# r(t) curve vector

Tags: vector-spaces, plane-curves

Here's the problem:

Integrate $f$ over the given curve.
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{x+y^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\qquad C: y=\frac{x^2}{2} \text{ from } (1,1/2) \text{ to } (0,0)
$$

In the solutions manual it says that 
$$
r(t) = (1-t)i + \frac{(1-t)^2}{2}j
$$

I can deal with this after that. The only thing I don't understand is how to get the $r(t)$ vector above. I can't find it anywhere on the internet.

Thanks in advance! And sorry, I don't know Latex.

Comment: $C$ is the graph of the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ on $[0,1]$. The usual parametrization of $C$ is obtained using $x=t$ and $y=f(t)$, $t\in[0,1]$ and the curve is traveled from $(0,f(0))=(0,0)$ to $(1,f(1))=(1,\frac{1}{2})$.


Here, the curve has the opposite orientation, so we obtain its parametrization by using the substitution $t\to 1-t$. This is how is obtain $r$ in the solution manual.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'd like a curve $r(t)$ that traces the curve $y = \frac 12 x^2$ from $(1,1/2)$ to $(0,0)$.

In general, it's fairly easy to make a curve that follows a function $y = f(x)$ between two $x$-values.  All you need to do is:

- find an $x(t)$ that goes from one $x$ value to the other
- let $y(t) = f(x(t))$
- set $r(t) = x(t)i + y(t)j$

In this case, we want to graph $y = \frac 12 x^2$ from $x = 1$ to $x=0$.  First, we need an $x(t)$ that starts at $1$ and ends at $0$.  One easy solution is to set $x(t) = 1-t$, letting $t$ go from $0$ to $1$.

In general, we can find a linear function for which $x(0) = a$ and $x(1) = b$ by setting $x(t) = a + (b - a)t$.

Once you've done that, you need to set $y(t) = \frac 12 [x(t)]^2 = \frac 12 (1-t)^2$. Now, we can just set
$$
r(t) = (1-t)i + \frac 12 (1-t)^2 j
$$
and we're done.